# setBackgroundDrawableResource setScaleType(android)

Tags: android, xml

Sorry for my english, i want set background layout image only use `getWindow()`, like this:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_image);
```

And in `bg_image`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap

            android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

but the picture is stretched. How can I stretch proportional to the picture?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can specify a scale-type if you just assign the image to the window background.

What I have done in similar scenarios is wrap my layout in a parent `FrameLayout` with a child `ImageView` which does take the `scaleType` attribute. You then add in all of your existing layout views.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <!-- all of your other views here ... -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_image);` if i set FrameLayout i have error `........ invalid drawable tag FrameLayout`

Comment: Of all the solutions and hacks I have seen to try and tackle this issue, this is by far the most pragmatic one and it actually WORKS. Thank you.